# Spark consuming records only off of one Kafka topic partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming app that consumes off Kafka:

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](Set(kafkaTopic), kafkaParams)
)
```

Kafka parameters are default as in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

Everything works fine as long as the kafka topic has one partition. However, when it's more (2), Spark seems to be reading only off one of them. 
This is what I'm seeing in the logs:

```
17/07/28 12:08:15 INFO kafka010.KafkaRDD: Computing topic processedJobs, partition 0 offsets 20 -> 29
17/07/28 12:08:15 INFO kafka010.KafkaRDD: Beginning offset 0 is the same as ending offset skipping processedJobs 1
17/07/28 12:08:20 INFO kafka010.KafkaRDD: Beginning offset 29 is the same as ending offset skipping processedJobs 0
17/07/28 12:08:20 INFO kafka010.KafkaRDD: Beginning offset 0 is the same as ending offset skipping processedJobs 1
```

Output from `kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh --zookeeper $ZOOKEEPER --topic processedJobs --group counselor-01` gives:

```
Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
counselor-01    processedJobs                  0   29              29              0               none
counselor-01    processedJobs                  1   0               28              28              none
```

I thought this has to do with faulty offset committing, using this pattern:

```
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
  stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
}
```

I've then changed `enable.auto.commit` to `true` and removed commiting, however the problem still persists (the lag on one of the partitions just keep growing).

I'm running Spark 2.1.0 and Kafka 0.10.1.0 in docker environment. Any tips on what could be the issue here?

I've seen this topic: [Spark Structured Stream get messages from only one partition of Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239005/spark-structured-stream-get-messages-from-only-one-partition-of-kafka)
But with Kafka 0.10.0.1 I am getting:

```
WARN clients.NetworkClient: Bootstrap broker kafka:9092 disconnected
```

errors with spark

Comment: I have not worked on spark as such, but just wanted to add one pointer that when kafka is using partition one consumer will pick message only from one partition. So there needs to be multiple consumers. Not sure if there some setting for that in spark.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I don't think it's true. If there's only one consumer and many partitions, then that consumer should read from all partitions. At least that's what I've experienced when using ruby kafka client.

Comment: @sparrovv, thanks for the info. I will check about it and update myself soon on this. Only had to setup Kafka for one of devops project. Haven't worked much on it using code yet

Comment: I would assume that this is implementation dependant. There's nothing in the Kafka client, that manages partitions - the client subscribes to individual partitions. Spark ought to manage the Kafka clients in such a way, that there's one for each partition, but you'd have to check whether that's actually the case.